# Best way to archive vertical key table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table storing breadcrumbs pointing back at a financial transaction table's key in order to keep track of exactly which records were included in a given batch process. The key of the financial transaction table is a combination of 2 columns, one being a unique header record and the other being a sequence number.

So my table that I currently use to serve as an archive table has a structure that looks like this:

```
Id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
BatchProcessId INT NOT NULL,
HeaderId INT NOT NULL,
SequenceNumber INT NOT NULL
```

The data stored in this table is really just for auditing purposes and does not need to be searchable in an efficient manner. It also grows very large in size very quickly vertically since the source financial transaction table has hundreds of millions of rows and this table can hold millions of HeaderId\SequenceNumber records for a given BatchProcessId.

So I am thinking I could store it as a string in some kind of format in BLOB storage or something? Is there a better way to do this? I could store the BatchProcessId and then flatten the HeaderId/SequenceNumber combinations into a string like [1000,1][1000,2][1001,1]...

Then if the data ever needs to be audited, a function could be used to make the data vertical and searchable. Are there benefits of this approach versus just storing the data vertically? I am trying to drastically reduce the table size. Can the BLOB column be compressed if I go that route too?

Comment: If you are going to archive this outside the database export it to a text file then compress it. If you are going to keep the data in the database, you are better off leaving data as integer data type, int is stored very efficiently. You can also compress data in SQL...

Comment: I would agree with @under. If the size of the table is really a problem then export old data to a text file from which you can restore if you ever need to in the future.

Comment: Storing Ints as string is never going to improve storage efficiency. Either archive the data as suggested by @under or investigate [`VARDECIMAL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-db-vardecimal-storage-format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [table compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/enable-compression-on-a-table-or-index?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: If I were you, I used `NoSQL` for archive it.